Blazor WASM and ExcelDataReader are they compatible?
I need to read and parse Excel Spreadsheets in my Blazor application. Once I read the data I will persist it, but my main issue is that the Nuget package ExcelDataReader I am using throws an error when attempting to use which seems to indicate I cannot use it in a WASM application:
System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.BrowserFileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
   at ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(Stream fileStream, ExcelReaderConfiguration configuration)
   at CollectXScore.Web.ExcelFileReader.LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs ev) in D:\Intellaegis\CollectXScore\CollectXScore.Web\ExcelFileReader.cs:line 54
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0(Object state)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.PostAsync[TState](Task antecedent, Action`1 callback, TState state)

When doing the following:
public async void LoadFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs ev)
{
    IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> files = ev.GetMultipleFiles();
    foreach (IBrowserFile file in ev.GetMultipleFiles())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(file.ContentType);
        if (excelContentTypes.Contains(file.ContentType) || file.ContentType == "text/csv")
        {
            // Auto-detect format, supports:
            //  - Binary Excel files (2.0-2003 format; *.xls)
            //  - OpenXml Excel files (2007 format; *.xlsx, *.xlsb)
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                // Use the AsDataSet extension method
                // The result of each spreadsheet is in result.Tables
                var result = reader.AsDataSet();

                // Access data in the DataSet
                var dataTable = result.Tables[0];
                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(cell);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried using a memory stream also without success.
Was expecting be able to read the Excel file contents. Instead got unsupported result.

After a bunch research and playing around with the code, here is a working solution:
if (excelContentTypes.Contains(file.ContentType))
        {

            // Auto-detect format, supports:
            //  - Binary Excel files (2.0-2003 format; *.xls)
            //  - OpenXml Excel files (2007 format; *.xlsx, *.xlsb)
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(stream);
            stream.Position = 0; // Position will be the end of the file after the copy
            using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
            {

                // Use the AsDataSet extension method
                // The result of each spreadsheet is in result.Tables
                var result = reader.AsDataSet();

                // Access data in the DataSet
                var dataTable = result.Tables[0];
                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(cell);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

I found the following site which gave a good solution. Note it is using a memory stream so size of files can be an issue. A normal file stream might work and I will attempt that later:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38785
Additional Notes. The above mechanism seemed to work, but after a few tries it started failing. In the end I had to persist the file and read it back in like follows:
if (file.ContentType == "text/csv")
{
    System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
    // Previously persisted the file...
    FileStream source = File.Open("C:\\pathtofile\\myfilename, FileMode.Open); 
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateCsvReader(source))
    {
        // Use the AsDataSet extension method
        // The result of each spreadsheet is in result.Tables
        var result = reader.AsDataSet();

        // Access data in the DataSet
        var dataTable = result.Tables[0];
        var cnt = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            // Skip the first row, it is the header
            if (cnt > 0)
            {
                if (row != null && row.ItemArray != null)
                {
                    //Process the data...
                }
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(cnt);
            cnt++;
        }
    }
}

